# How to bypass SSL Pinning of an Android App

Tags: android, security, ssl, pinning, frida

I want to bypass the SSL pinning of an Android app using the Frida Server method.

I have followed the whole process described in this (https://blog.it-securityguard.com/the-stony-path-of-android-%F0%9F%A4%96-bug-bounty-bypassing-certificate-pinning/) tutorial.

**Below are the steps which I have followed/performed:**

0. Installed the Frida library and Frida-tools
1. Rooted my Android Device
2. Installed the target app
3. Downloaded the Frida server for my Device architecture
4. Sent the Frida Server to its path in Device
5. Granted the Frida server the necessary permissions
6. Have started the Frida Server
7. Got the Frida Script File ready
8. Now when I try to spawn an app it is raising the process is terminating as shown below:

[image: frida]

I am trying this from my Windows Laptop with a Real and rooted Android Device running Android lollipop 5.0.

I have tried it on other apps as well but it causes issues on them as well.

In my opinion, the issue is with the code within my Frida Script file.

If my Frida Script file is empty it is causing no issue but whenever I add the below line in the file it is causing the process to be terminated.

This is the line that is causing the issue.

`Java.perform(function (){    });`

The app is the device is getting started and immediately the console is showing the process as terminated. I am using `frida-server-12.7.22-android-arm.xz` as the server. I am pretty sure that the setup is fully right but the only issue is occurring while adding the above code to the Frida Script file.

Also `Java.IsAvailable` returns false.

Comment: As you neither post the app you are trying to hook nor the code you use for hooking one can only say: Yes it is possible to crash an app by code in Frida.